# Changing data in nested lists from string to float

Tags: python, python-2.7

im having some difficulty changing the data in a 2D list from a string to a float. I have been trying to use nested **for** loops but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

My data is in this format.

```
[['3.52', '0.95', '2.0', '1.52'],
['3.41', '0.95', '2.0', '1.6'],......]
```

my current method has been this.

```
for item in data: 
    for n in item:
         n=float(n)
```

I am using python 2.7

Comment: That looks like a 2D list.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a 2d list. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but you're not actually updating the values in your array with your current code.  There are a number of ways to do this - simplest, just find the indices of each element, and convert with `float()`.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[i])):
        data[i][j] = float(data[i][j])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate()` in inner for-loop to retrieve index (say `i`), then use `item[i] = float(n)`

Answer (score 1):

Try with `map` function (in Python 2):

```
data = [['3.52', '0.95', '2.0', '1.52'],['3.41', '0.95', '2.0', '1.6']]
result = [map(float, item) for item in data]
print(result)
```

In Python 3:

```
data = [['3.52', '0.95', '2.0', '1.52'],['3.41', '0.95', '2.0', '1.6']]
result = [list(map(float, item)) for item in data]
print(result)
```

result will be:

```
[[3.52, 0.95, 2.0, 1.52], [3.41, 0.95, 2.0, 1.6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your loop into a list comprehension with a map:

```
data = [['3.52', '0.95', '2.0', '1.52'],['3.41', '0.95', '2.0', '1.6']]

data_flts = [map(float, i) for i in data]
```

`data_flts` is the desired list of sublists with floats. `map` applies `float` function to every element of sublist i in your original list, here called `data`. On Python 3.X you would need to use `list(map(...))` to turn `map` output into a list.

The problem with your original program was that you didn't save your number in any way, just overwrote it in every iteration of the inner loop. Simple fixes include appending the number to a list.

Comment: In case anyone wonders: this was the first answer on the page to use `map`